# How to prove this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$z=\frac{y}{f((x^2)+(y^2))}$$

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{y}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{z}{y^2}.$$

This looks obvious but spent already a lot of time on it.

Any Hint or idea?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Hint: just find the necessary derivatives, substitute them into the equation and see if it holds

Comment: Now I have this:   (z/y) - 4z * (f ' ((x^2) + (y^2)) / f((x^2) + (y^2)))) = (z/(y^2))

Comment: I can't decipher this, please use MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $z= \frac{y}{f(x,y)}$ with respect to x is $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= \frac{-y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{f^2}$ and the derivative of $z= \frac{y}{f(x,y)}$ with respect to y is $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}= \frac{f(x,y)- y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}{f^2}$.

Further, since $f(x, y)= f(x^2+ y^2)$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= 2x f'$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= 2y f'$ where f' is the derivative of f with respect to the single variable.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{y}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{z}{y^2}.$$
Note that $ f'=\frac {df}{d(x^2+y^2)}$ for simplicity
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2xf' \,;\, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2yf'$$
$$\frac{1}{x}\left (\frac{-2xyf'}{f^2}\right ) + \frac{1}{y}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{fy}.$$
$$\frac{1}{x}\left (\frac{-2xyf'}{f^2}\right ) + \frac{1}{y}\left(\frac{f-yf'2y}{f^2}\right)=\frac{1}{fy}.$$
$$\frac{1}{x}\left (\frac{-2xyf'}{f^2}\right ) + \frac{1}{y}\left(\frac{-yf'2y}{f^2}\right)=0$$
$$-\left (\frac{2yf'}{f^2}\right ) + \left(\frac{-2yf'}{f^2}\right)=0$$

Are you sure it's $f(x^2+y^2)$ and not $f(x^2-y^2)$ ???